# LUKS fails to mount drive after reinstalling Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, encryption, luks

I had to reinstall linux on my laptop and had my previous installation backed up to a luks encrypted drive. After the reinstall I am unabled to mount the drive. Instead it throws an error.

```
Error unlocking /dev/sdb1: Failed to activate device: Operation not permitted
```

I checked the password multiple times and it is the one I've set. Anyone got an idea how to fix this?

Comment: What's the [exact command you're using](https://superuser.com/posts/1607750/edit) (no passwords please!), and are you running it as an ordinary user or as root?

Comment: Without providing more details, nobody can provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently it was a typo in the password, which probably happened when I copied
it before reinstalling. I hadn't written down the password, but photographed it, and when I pasted it back into my password manager after the reinstallation, I made a
typo. Smart as I am, however, I deleted the picture right after I had pasted the
password.

How I finally found out about the typo was by 'simply' bruteforcing the
passphrase using a programm called `bruteforce-luks`. However, because it would take 'a bit of time' to check all combinations of a password longer than atleast 20 characters I had to find some shortcuts.

The first shortcut was that I knew the exact length of the passphrase. And even better than that I already had a lot of additional information about the passphrase, given that I had a – to my concern – atleast mostly correct passphrase.

The second shortcut was that given the nature of a keyboard only a few other possibilities for each character would come into play. The accidental switching of two neighbour characters was another option.

All this combined lead to a drastic decrease in the number of passphrases to check and with a simple script, the creation of the permutations with these contrains was easily automated. And after a few hundred passwords and a bit of luck, I actually found the lost password.

So even while this was kind of fun to figure out, I guess the moral of the story is to double or even triple check data when copying it.

Comment: Good job figuring this out. The real moral of the story is to always make sure your backup is restorable before you need it :) Also, make it automatic. Your disk won't warn you before its sudden death.

Comment: `cryptsetup` option `--verify-passphrase` would have helped to avoid wrong statements like "I checked the password multiple times and it is the one I've set. "